# SQL QUERY FOR DATABASE ON Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

my query isn't working at all and been working to see what's wrong but can't find it. says that have two values that are the same but honestly I am doing my best to proof-read my code:

```
SELECT
"HQCO"."HQCo",
"HQCO"."Name",
"JCJP"."Contract",
"JCJP"."Item",
"JCJP"."Phase",
"JCCP"."CostType",
"JCCI"."Item",
"JCCI"."Description",
"JCCP"."Phase",
"JCJP"."Description",
"JCCT"."Description",
"JCCH"."UM",
"JCCP"."CurrEstUnits",
"JCCP"."CurrEstCost",
"JCCP"."ActualUnits",
"JCCP"."ActualCost",
"JCCM"."Description",
"JCJP"."JCCo",
"JCCP"."ProjCost",
"JCCP"."RemainCmtdCost",
"JCCP"."ProjPlug",
"JCCP"."Mth",
"JCCI"."BilledAmt",
"JCCM"."BilledAmt",
"JCCM"."udGEACrev",
"JCCP"."Job",
"JCCM"."Department",
"JCJM"."ProjectMgr",
"JCMP"."Name"

FROM
 (
(((((("Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCP" "JCCP" 
      INNER JOIN
         "Viewpoint"."dbo"."HQCO" "HQCO" 
         ON "JCCP"."JCCo" = "HQCO"."HQCo")
      INNER JOIN
         "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCT" "JCCT" 
         ON ("JCCP"."PhaseGroup" = "JCCT"."PhaseGroup") 
         AND 
         (
             "JCCP"."CostType" = "JCCT"."CostType"
         )
) 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
         "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCH" "JCCH" 
         ON (((("JCCP"."JCCo" = "JCCH"."JCCo") 
         AND 
         (
            "JCCP"."Job" = "JCCH"."Job"
         )
) 
         AND 
         (
            "JCCP"."PhaseGroup" = "JCCH"."PhaseGroup"
         )
) 
         AND 
         (
            "JCCP"."Phase" = "JCCH"."Phase"
         )
) 
         AND 
         (
            "JCCP"."CostType" = "JCCH"."CostType"
         )
 ) 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
             "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCJP" "JCJP" 
          ON ((("JCCP"."JCCo" = "JCJP"."JCCo") 
          AND 
         (
            "JCCP"."Job" = "JCJP"."Job"
         )
) 
          AND 
         (
            "JCCP"."PhaseGroup" = "JCJP"."PhaseGroup"
         )
) 
          AND 
         (
            "JCCP"."Phase" = "JCJP"."Phase"
         )
)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
          "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCI" "JCCI" 
         ON (("JCJP"."JCCo" = "JCCI"."JCCo") 
         AND 
         (
            "JCJP"."Contract" = "JCCI"."Contract"
         )
) 
         AND 
         (
             "JCJP"."Item" = "JCCI"."Item"
         )
)
      INNER JOIN
         "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCCM" "JCCM" 
         ON ("JCCI"."JCCo" = "JCCM"."JCCo") 
         AND 
         (
            "JCCI"."Contract" = "JCCM"."Contract"
         )
) 
       INNER JOIN
          "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCJM" "JCJM" 
           ON ("JCCM"."JCCo" = "JCJM"."JCCo") 
           AND 
         (
           "JCCM"."Contract" = "JCJM"."Job"
          )
   )
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      "Viewpoint"."dbo"."JCMP" "JCMP" 
       ON ("JCJM"."JCCo" = "JCMP"."JCCo") 
       AND 
       (
          "JCJM"."ProjectMgr" = "JCMP"."ProjectMgr"
       )




WHERE
   "JCCP"."Mth" < {ts '2017-04-02 00:00:00'} 
   AND "JCJP"."JCCo" = 1 
   AND "JCJM"."ProjectMgr" = 8 
   AND "JCCM"."Department" = '10' 
    ORDER BY
       "JCJP"."Contract", "JCJP"."Item", "JCJP"."Phase", "JCCP"."CostType"
```

As you can see all tables and values are related and joined with inner and outer joins to complement the tables. It is for a report

Comment: What is the error message you are getting. Can you paste it here?

Comment: Could not create a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct. "An item with the same key has already been added

Comment: Hm... What tool are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query have multiple problems.

```
1) Problem with parenthese (too '(')
2) You use left outer join on table and you test a zone of this table -> null will be excluded like it
3) Multiples Zones in your select with same name
4) Quotes for zones and alias for tables are not necessary
```

Try this query remainded :

```
SELECT
HQCO.HQCo,
HQCO.Name,
JCJP.Contract,
JCJP.Item,
JCJP.Phase,
JCCP.CostType,
JCCI.Item,
JCCI.Description Desc1,
JCCP.Phase,
JCJP.Description Desc2,
JCCT.Description Desc3,
JCCH.UM,
JCCP.CurrEstUnits,
JCCP.CurrEstCost,
JCCP.ActualUnits,
JCCP.ActualCost,
JCCM.Description Desc4,
JCJP.JCCo,
JCCP.ProjCost,
JCCP.RemainCmtdCost,
JCCP.ProjPlug,
JCCP.Mth,
JCCI.BilledAmt BilledAmt1,
JCCM.BilledAmt BilledAmt2,
JCCM.udGEACrev,
JCCP.Job,
JCCM.Department,
JCJM.ProjectMgr,
JCMP.Name Name2

FROM
      Viewpoint.dbo.JCCP  
      INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.HQCO ON JCCP.JCCo = HQCO.HQCo
      INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCT ON JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCT.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.CostType = JCCT.CostType
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCH ON JCCP.JCCo = JCCH.JCCo AND JCCP.Job = JCCH.Job 
      AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCCH.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase = JCCH.Phase AND JCCP.CostType = JCCH.CostType
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJP ON JCCP.JCCo = JCJP.JCCo AND JCCP.Job = JCJP.Job 
      AND JCCP.PhaseGroup = JCJP.PhaseGroup AND JCCP.Phase = JCJP.Phase AND JCJP.JCCo = 1 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCI ON JCJP.JCCo = JCCI.JCCo AND JCJP.Contract = JCCI.Contract AND JCJP.Item = JCCI.Item
      INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCCM ON JCCI.JCCo = JCCM.JCCo AND JCCI.Contract = JCCM.Contract
      INNER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCJM ON JCCM.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo AND JCCM.Contract = JCJM.Job
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Viewpoint.dbo.JCMP ON JCJM.JCCo = JCMP.JCCo AND JCJM.ProjectMgr = JCMP.ProjectMgr

WHERE
   JCCP.Mth < {ts '2017-04-02 00:00:00'} 
   AND JCJM.ProjectMgr = 8 
   AND JCCM.Department = '10' 
ORDER BY JCJP.Contract, JCJP.Item, JCJP.Phase, JCCP.CostType
```

Comment: Makes sense but still my SQL Server Report builder give me the same error prompt which is : 
Could not create a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct.

"An item with the same key has already been added"

Comment: In fact I thought about making the common variables from different tables like this.

FROM JCJP AS t1
INNER JOIN JCCP AS t2
     ON t2.Phase = t1.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN JCCI AS t3
     ON t3.Description = t1.PrimaryKey
AND ON t3.BilledAmt = t1.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN JCCM AS t4
     ON t4.Description = t1.PrimaryKey
AND ON t4.BilledAmt = t1.PrimaryKey